# How can I add the softwares I have installed from USC of kubuntu 12.04 into kubuntu 12.10 iso installation file

Tags: 12.04, installation, 12.10, software-center, kubuntu

I am currently using Kubuntu 12.04. I don't have strong high speed Internet connection and managed to get Kubuntu 12.10. I found that it's size is about 1GB. I have a lot of  softwares installed in my current Kubuntu 12.04 via Ubuntu Software Center

I would like to Add these software to Kubuntu 12.10 installation iso file. I don't want to download packages from Ubuntu customization kit (UCK) or similar software.

I don't prefer using APTonCD or similar software. What I want is to add these software into this Kubuntu 12.10, so that they appear along with the default application which will be installed as default when the OS is installed. Is this possible?

Comment: please.. help me with this, isn't there anyone who can help me out...PLEASE

Comment: paisa thannal vote tharam :p

Answer (score 0):

## No you can't

Belive me, you can't copy installed s/w to different version of software. But you may can install some packages via aptoncd but still highly dangerous and may lead to system crash .

Comment: That's not true ,check this link out:[Remastering an “Ubuntu alternate” ISO with Ubuntu Customization Kit – the complete guide](http://fabrizioballiano.net/2007/11/27/remastering-an-ubuntu-alternate-iso-with-ubuntu-customization-kit-the-complete-guide/).And please help me out with this...(TAKE NOTE THAT I WANT THE PROGRAMS TO BE INSTALLED BY DEFAULT). THE PROBLEM IS THAT I CAN'T DIGEST THE TECHNICALITY WITH THIS LINK.MATHRAMALA, IF U HELP ME WITH THIS I CAN ASSURE U AN UPOTE FOR ALL UR POSTS...,PASISA THARATHE :-) ;-}

Comment: @Suhailcholassery : lol അതു ഞാന്‍ തമാഷ പറഞതാ ,but linked article is about remastering iso which is different topic :-)

Comment: then how can i do that

Comment: :o You can't , it is different os, each package is to be updated, It lead you to the dependancy hell.  Viswasichalum illenkilum ithanu answer

Comment: i trust u, but can i do it with the with installation file of KUBUNTU 12.04?? or can i do that  after updating my system into 12.10

Comment: ^yes you can add it in kubuntu 12.04 iso using uck,remastersys or relinux

Comment: then how,please explain...and can we chat using facebook or some thing else.. i am sick of this commenting it takes so long...,and i don't have enough reputation to chat via askubuntu

Comment: ^Then it is another question, which is already answered in askubuntu, just search :),

Comment: www.facebook.com/aboobacker.mk

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other replies that you will not be able to have the apps installed by default unless you build a custom remix. However, you can make installing them after installing the OS a bit easier.
First, install synaptic package manager with the command:
`sudo apt-get install synaptic`
 Then open it & search for and install Ubuntu Software center. Next, open Ubuntu Software Center & go to file>>sync between computers. Now you should be able to see the differences. This of course assumes you had turned sync on in your previous Ubuntu installation. If not, I think you may have to do it all manually.